# c++ why must use using keyword in base class to call non virtual same name functions?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, virtual

I am having below code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Base {
public:
    void operator()(std::string str) {
        std::cout << "base str: " << str << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void operator()(double d) {
        std::cout << "base double: "<< d << std::endl;
    }

};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    void operator()(double d) override {
        std::cout << "derived double: "<< d << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived derived;
    derived(8.0);
    derived(std::string("hi"));
}
```

The above code wont compile as it will complain that `no match for call to ‘(Derived) (std::string)’`, but if I change derived class into below,

```
class Derived: public Base {
public:
    using Base::operator();
    void operator()(double d) override {
        std::cout << "derived double: "<< d << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The code will compile and works fine, I wonder why is this the case, as I am under the impression that all the `Base` class public function will be in `Derived`?

Comment: Because in **first case** `void Derived::operator()(double)` overrides `void Base::operator()(double)` but not `void Base::operator()(std::string)`. While in the **second case** you're explicitly bringing both of the Base's overloads into the `Derived` class so that now the `string` version is also there in the derived class.

Comment: There might be a better duplicate, but it has to do with how name lookups work.

Comment: One function shadows the other. The reason is probably to make derived classes more resistant to bases suddenly adding new methods with the same name.

Comment: Name lookup happens **before** overload resolution. Name lookup finds `Derived::operator()(double)` (and nothing else). Overload resolution then fails. Those are the rules, the methods in `Base` are never considered. That they are public is irrelevant.

Comment: title: "c++ why must use using keyword in base class" its in the derived not in the base class

Answer (score 1):

In the **second case** you're explicitly bringing both of the Base's overloads into the `Derived` class so that now the `string` version is also there in the derived class. This means that here the lookup finds a `string` parameter version that can be used and so this succeeds.

On the other hand, in the **first case** there the lookup finds the `void Derived::operator()(double)` and stops looking any further. And since there is no `string` version, this gives the mentioned error.